# Stub Model Save Method in Rspec/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This should be simple, but i can't get it to work. I want to stub an :

```
@alliance.save
```

so that it returns true. I tried :

```
Alliance.stub(:save).and_return(true)
```

but it won't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `Alliance.stub(:save)` would affect calls to `Alliance.save`. You want `@alliance.stub(:save).and_return(true)`.

[Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) has a useful method `any_instance`, so you could do something like `Alliance.any_instance.stubs(:save).returns(true)`, which would (as the name implies) stub the `save` method for any instance of `Alliance`.

Comment: hmm, i actually think it's the same since save is an instance method. Whatever the case, i cannot really access @alliance, because it's like "@alliance = Alliance.new(params[:alliance])" in a standard create method. I just want to bypass the save validations because i can't seem to be able to pass post variables through ":post :create, :name => 'whatever'"

Comment: Mentioning that you want to stub the method on an instance variable created in a controller might help you get more accurate responses. ;)

Comment: As an afterthought, you should be able to pass params in. I [do this successfully myself](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rails-book/blob/master/spec/controllers/microposts_controller_spec.rb#L35) (code from the Rails Tutorial book).

Comment: i've actually done that too in previous tests, but for single values. Maybe i should pass the whole :alliance param, hmm. Deserves an attempt.

Comment: YES ! It worked like "post :create, :alliance => {:name => 'whatever'}". Nice idea thanx ;)

Comment: As an after-after thought, RSpec docs say: "We strongly recommend that you use RSpec’s mocking/stubbing framework
to intercept class level calls like :find, :create and
even :new to introduce mock instances instead of real active_record instances. This allows you to focus your specs on the things that the controller does and not worry about complex validations and relationships." So maybe stubbing `Alliance.new` is the way to go? Also: glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 8):

Using the new RSpec syntax:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Alliance).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
describe AllianceController do
  let(:alliance) { mock_model(Alliance) }

  describe "#<controller action>" do
    before do
      Alliance.stub :new => alliance
    end

    context "valid alliance" do
      before do
        alliance.stub :save => true
      end

      it "should ..." do

      end
    end
  end
end
```

The inner context allows you to work with an Alliance mock which has the save method stubbed to return true.

Comment: +1 After getting more details from SpyrosP in the comments, I think this is probably the best method for testing a controller (even though they got their params to work).